# Can files deleted in other branch be 'undeleted' with a manual git merge?

Tags: git, merge

I'm trying to merge in some changes from another branch (e.g. `that` branch) . The changes made to existing files on `that` branch I would like to keep, but `that` branch also deletes some files, and those files should not be deleted on `this` branch.

Merging normally removes the files from `this`.

I'm trying to use (while on the `this` branch) `git merge --no-commit that` to keep the deleted files. Is it possible?

While in the merge I try to restore the file by using `git checkout --ours dontDeleteMe.txt`, but I get `error: pathspec 'dontDeleteMe.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git.`, even though `dontDeleteMe.txt` is present in `this` branch (i.e. the `HEAD` when I started the merge).
`git checkout --theirs dontDeleteMe.txt` and `git checkout dontDeleteMe.txt` also give the same result.

Am I trying to achieve the impossible here, or just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform `git merge --no-commit that`.

You have to specify the revision from which you want to take `dontDeleteMe.txt` as `dontDeleteMe.txt` is deleted during the merge.

Use `git checkout this -- dontDeleteMe.txt` or `git checkout HEAD~1 -- dontDeleteMe.txt`

The checkout parameters `--ours` and `--theirs` only work for conflicts.